# How to launching 2 CUDA kernels concurrently ？

Tags: concurrency, cuda, profiling, nsight

I tried to create 4 streams to launch 4 kernels concurrently, but it seems it run serially using nsight.

**My Hardware: RTX2060**

My test code is as follows:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 1000000

__global__ void kernel_1() 
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        sum = sum + tan(0.1) * tan(0.1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int n_streams = 4; 
    cudaStream_t *streams = (cudaStream_t *)malloc(n_streams * sizeof(cudaStream_t));
    for (int i = 0; i < n_streams; i++) {
        cudaStreamCreateWithFlags(&streams[i], cudaStreamNonBlocking);
    }
    dim3 block(1);
    dim3 grid(1);

    for (int i = 0; i < n_streams; i++) {
        kernel_1 << <grid, block, 0, streams[i] >> >();
        kernel_1 << <grid, block, 0, streams[i] >> >();
        kernel_1 << <grid, block, 0, streams[i] >> >();
        kernel_1 << <grid, block, 0, streams[i] >> >();
    }

    printf("done\n");
    return 0;
}
```

timeline shows as this:
[kernel running timeline shotcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwBRR.png)

Comment: Try launching them with a for loop each (i.e. launch all `kernel_1` instances first, then all `kernel_2` etc)

Comment: There is latency in scheduling at different areas in the execution pipeline. Your kernel isn't doing any work because of compiler optimization, so it will be impossible to tell anything from your experiment. Make `sum` participate in a memory write (or even appear to to the compiler) and the picture might look different

Comment: @AnderBiguri  Thanks,  I 've trid ,  but it appears serially as well .

Comment: Is the overhead of the kernel launch longer than the time it takes to process the run the kernel?

Comment: @cwharris: given this kernel is compiled to a  null stub and does nothing, absolutely

Comment: There is a CUDA sample code [`concurrentKernels`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#concurrent-kernels).  It may still be difficult to witness concurrency on a WDDM GPU.

Comment: @talonmies Thankks   I've test convolution samples with 4 streams and 4block per kernel, but timeline shows it runs  serially as well .

Comment: @RobertCrovella I 've tried this kernel . it shows serially in the same.. btw, what is WDDM GPU? Is GPU which has Windows Display Driver Model？？  What if I test on linux ??

Comment: I have a windows 10 machine with a RTX 2070 GPU.  Using CUDA 10.1, VS 2019, I built the `concurrentKernels` sample code as a Release project.  The I run the code from a command prompt, and I get output like this: `[concurrentKernels.exe] - Starting...
GPU Device 0: "GeForce RTX 2070" with compute capability 7.5

> Detected Compute SM 7.5 hardware with 36 multi-processors
Expected time for serial execution of 8 kernels = 0.080s
Expected time for concurrent execution of 8 kernels = 0.010s
Measured time for sample = 0.012s
Test passed`  So I would say it seems to work fine.

Comment: Depending on how you use the profiler and what profiler you are using, the profiler may serialize concurrent kernels.

Comment: @RobertCrovella   I've tried  , you are right , timeline of  nsight shows  serially., but if I run the exe outside without nsight, the performance of muti-stream is much more better

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Please make your comment into an answer.